# In julia, why is the memory allocated the same, but the number of allocations vastly different?

Tags: julia

The reference article I'm using comes from the post answering the following question: [Should I use mutable or immutable containers for agent based models in Julia?](https://www.juliabloggers.com/should-i-use-mutable-or-immutable-containers-for-agent-based-models-in-julia/)

I'm running some experiments in Julia that require monte carlo simulation, but my code has a large memory footprint, so I decided to do a deep dive on understanding Julia's memory model. I found this article to be useful, but one concept I'm struggling with is the last section of the tutorial where the immutable and mutable objects have a differing number of memory allocations, but the SAME amount of memory allocated.

For the function `gM(n)`, the number of allocations is proportional to `n`, but for `gI(n)` the allocations appear to be constant. Is this due to the fact that the mutable struct has it's allocations take place on the heap, whereas the mutable struct still requires approximately the same amount of memory, but this is done on the stack?

I suppose that when using the `@time` macro, julia reports the amount of memory allocated on the heap and not necessarily the total amount of memory utilized by the program. Correct me where you see fit please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `gI` and `gM` are allocating on the heap, as far as I understand. A vector will always be on the heap, unless you're using something like the StaticArrays package. The difference is that the vector of immutable structures in `gI` is a single contiguous piece of memory containing the data of the objects packed one next to the other. In `gM`, each mutable object causes a separate allocation, and the vector holds pointers to these objects. That's why there's one allocation for immutable, of the whole array, and one allocation per object for mutable. The memory reported is the total of all memory allocation operations, not the final footprint.

I'd definitely recommend using the immutable approach, along with the Accessors.jl package. Note that compiler optimizations can usually produce code where only the relevant fields are read or written to, leaving untouched the remaining data of the "old" object, just like mutable code in C would do.